# Getting information from ID's

Tags: php, domdocument

First off, I'm brand new to PHP so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, second of all sorry if this title is incorrect.

Now, what I'm trying to do is create an overlay for a game that I play. My code for the overlay works perfectly, and now I'm working on my HTML file which gets its information from a website and outputs it. The code on the website looks like this:

```
<span id="example1">Information I want</span>
<span id="example2">More Info I want</span>
...
<span id="example3">And some more</span>
```

Now what I want to do is create a PHP script which goes in and finds elements by their names and gives me the information in those span tags. Here's what I've tried so far, it's not working however (no surprise):

```
//Some HTML here
<?php
$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->validateOnParse = true;
$doc->Load('www.website.com');

echo "Example1: " . $doc->getElementById('example1') . "\n";
?>
//More HTML
```

To be honest, I have no clue what I'm doing. If anyone could show me an example of how to do this properly, or to point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: Just glancing at this, I'd suggest you use curl instead of load. More secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text between open and close tags is a Text Node.

Just write `$doc->getElementById('example1')->nodeValue`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried your solution and it's not working for me. However, after looking through the source code some more I found this: http://i.imgur.com/xFS2nAI.png How would I go about getting the nodeValue, or data? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems along the right lines, but you're missing a few things.

First of all, your `load` call is literally looking for a file named "www.website.com". If it's a remote file, you must include the `http://` prefix.

Then, you are attempting to echo out the node itself, whereas you want its value (ie. its contents).
Try `$doc->getElementById("example1")->nodeValue` instead.

That should do it. You may want to add `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` so that any errors in the source file won't destroy your page with PHP errors. Also, I would suggest using `loadHTMLFile` instead of `load`, as this will be more lenient towards malformed documents.

Comment: I tried your nodeValue solution, and it didn't quite work. After looking at the source code for the site the information which I want is setup like so:

span#example1 ->
childNodes: NodeList[1] ->
0: text ->
data: "Info"

I got this from the properties tab in inspect element.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xFS2nAI.png That's how the layout looks like, I'm not sure why it doesn't work either. Is there a way of accessing the data field?

Comment: What are you getting in the PHP side of things?

Comment: I'm just getting a space character from firstChild, and nodeValue.

Comment: Are you sure the contents aren't being added dynamically? If you right-click and View Source, is the data actually there?

Comment: The data is there, however it's a timer which counts down and dynamically changes.

Comment: Yeah, using PHP to access it will only get the content as it appears when the page loads, in the original source. Unless you start parsing and executing the JavaScript, you're stuck with that.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, how should I go about getting this information so that it constantly updates?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really help you there without more detailed information about exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm creating an overlay for a game that I play, which is to get information from this website to display in-game. It's a timer which counts down until the next time a boss will spawn so players won't have to go to their web browser to check the information, it'll be right there in-game.

Answer (score 1):

you can use getElementById:

$a = $doc->getElementById("example1");
var_dump($a); so you will see what you want to echo or put, or something.

You can also make all the names i HTML as example[] end then foreach the example array, so you can get element by id from example array with just one row of code